# Solving recurrences: Substitution method

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

I'm trying to follow Cormen's book "Introduction to Algorithms" (page 59, I believe) about substitution method for solving recurrences. I don't get the notation used for MERGE-SORT substitution:

```
T(n) ≤ 2(c ⌊n/2⌋lg(⌊n/2⌋)) + n
≤ cn lg(n/2) + n
= cn lg n - cn lg 2 + n
= cn lg n - cn + n
≤ cn lg n
```

Part I don't understand is how do you turn ⌊n/2⌋ to n/2 assuming that it denotes recursion. Can you explain the substitution method and its general thought process (especially the math induction part) in a simple and easily understandable way ? I know there's a great answer of that sort about big-O notation here in SO.

Comment: `⌊n/2⌋ = n/2 - {n/2} ≤ n/2` is used.

Comment: Your formula shows Gauss brackets (`floor`) instead of square brackets, and this makes perfect sense in the context. Are you sure Cormen did not actually mean Gauss brackets?

Comment: @thiton The square ones are due to Gauss, and the half brackets are due to Knuth. They both mean floor.

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the substitution method is to bound a function defined by a recurrence via strong induction. I'm going to assume that `T(n)` is an upper bound on the number of comparisons merge sort uses to sort `n` elements and define it by the following recurrence with boundary condition `T(1) = 0`.

```
T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + n - 1.
```

Cormen et al. use `n` instead of `n - 1` for simplicity and cheat by using `floor` twice. Let's not cheat.

Let `H(n)` be the hypothesis that `T(n) ≤ c n lg n`. Technically we should choose `c` right now, so let's set `c = 100`. Cormen et al. opt to write down statements that hold for every (positive) `c` until it becomes clear what `c` should be, which is an optimization.

The base cases are `H(1)` and `H(2)`, namely `T(1) ≤ 0` and `T(2) ≤ 2 c`. Okay, we don't need any comparisons to sort one element, and `T(2) = T(1) + T(1) + 1 = 1 < 200`.

Inductively, when `n ≥ 3`, assume for all `1 ≤ n' < n` that `H(n')` holds. We need to prove `H(n)`.

```
T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + n - 1
     ≤ c floor(n/2) lg floor(n/2) + T(ceil(n/2)) + n - 1
         by the inductive hypothesis H(floor(n/2))
     ≤ c floor(n/2) lg floor(n/2) + c ceil(n/2) lg ceil(n/2) + n - 1
         by the inductive hypothesis H(ceil(n/2))
     ≤ c floor(n/2) lg (n/2) + c ceil(n/2) lg ceil(n/2) + n - 1
         since 0 < floor(n/2) ≤ n/2 and lg is increasing
```

Now we have to deal with the consequences of our honesty and bound `lg ceil(n/2)`.

```
lg ceil(n/2) = lg (n/2) + lg (ceil(n/2) / (n/2))
             < lg (n/2) + lg ((n/2 + 1) / (n/2))
                 since 0 < ceil(n/2) ≤ n/2 + 1 and lg is increasing
             = lg (n/2) + log (1 + 2/n) / log 2
             ≤ lg (n/2) + 2/(n log 2)
                 by the inequality log (1 + x) ≤ x, which can be proved with calculus
```

Okay, back to bounding `T(n)`.

```
T(n) ≤ c floor(n/2) lg (n/2) + c ceil(n/2) (lg (n/2) + 2/(n log 2)) + n - 1
         since 0 < floor(n/2) ≤ n/2 and lg is increasing
     = c n lg n - c n + n + 2 c ceil(n/2) / (n log 2) - 1
         since floor(n/2) + ceil(n/2) = n and lg (n/2) = lg n - 1
     ≤ c n lg n - (c - 1) n + 2 c/log 2
         since ceil(n/2) ≤ n
     ≤ c n lg n
         since, for all n' ≥ 3, we have (c - 1) n' = 99 n' ≥ 297 > 200/log 2 ≈ 288.539.
```

#### Commentary

I guess this doesn't explain the why very well, but (hopefully) at least the derivations are correct in all of the details. People who write proofs like these often skip the base cases and ignore `floor` and `ceil` because, well, the details usually are just an annoyance that  affects the constant `c` (which most computer scientists not named Knuth don't care about).

To me, the substitution method is for confirming a guess rather than formulating one. The interesting question is how one comes up with a guess. Personally, if the recurrence is (i) not something that looks like Fibonacci (e.g., linear homogeneous recurrences) and (ii) not covered by [Akra–Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_method), a generalization of the Master Theorem, then I'm going to have some trouble coming up with a good guess.

Also, I should mention the most common failure mode of the substitution method: if one can't quite choose `c` to be a large enough to swallow the extra terms from the subproblems, then the bound may be wrong. On the other hand, more base cases might suffice. In the preceding proof, I used two base cases because I couldn't prove the very last inequality unless I knew that `n > 2/log 2`.